# Why can't I push from PyCharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I'm a new GitHub user, and this question may be a trivial newbie problem. So I apologize in advance.

I'm using PyCharm for a Python project. I've set up a Git repository for the project and uploaded the files manually through the Git website. I also linked the repository to my PyCharm project.

When I modify a file, PyCharm allows me to "commit" it, but when I try to "push" it, I get a PyCharm pop-up error message saying "Push rejected." No further information is provided. How do I figure out what went wrong -- and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you push from an external shell?

Comment: Try manually pushing using the command line (e.g. `git push origin master`) and check if you see an error message. There might be a custom commit hook that requires your code to conform to some standard.

Comment: Try `git push upstream upstreammaster:master`

Comment: "uploaded the files manually through the Git website". How did u done it? can u explain the steps?

Answer (score 1):

If you manually uploaded files to the Github by dropping them, it now likely has a different history than your local files.

One way you could get around this is to store all of your changes in a different folder, do a `git pull` in pycharm, abandoning your changes so you are up to date with origin/master, then commit the files and push as you have been doing.